# VSCode disable emmet abbreviation editor on first line

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I disable Emmet abbreviation as first suggestion in vscode or move it to the end of the suggestion list?

It's not convenient to always jump down to pick something.

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Two steps:

1. `Emmet: Show Suggestions as Snippets` enable

> // If `true`, then Emmet suggestions will show up as snippets
> allowing you to order them as per `editor.snippetSuggestions` setting.

2. `Editor: Snippet Suggestions` set to `bottom`

   // Controls whether snippets are shown with other suggestions and how they are sorted.
   //  - top: Show snippet suggestions on top of other suggestions.
   //  - bottom: Show snippet suggestions below other suggestions.
   //  - inline: Show snippets suggestions with other suggestions.
   //  - none: Do not show snippet suggestions.

VsCode settings:

```
 "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
 "editor.snippetSuggestions": "bottom"
```

Comment: The issue with `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "bottom"` is that it puts user snippets at the bottom.